# PyQGIS - draw a line between start- and endpoint using tracing to fit into another line

Tags: pyqgis, geometry

I have 2 vector layers, "pipes" and "fibres".
The lines in the pipes layer are already drawn.
Now i want to draw a line in the fibres layer from a start point to an endpoint, but the line should trace the shortest line in the pipes layer.

In QGIS i would enable the tracing tool, click on the start- and endpoint in the fibres layer and the new line would snap into the "pipes".

Is there an easy way to implement this in PyQGIS?

Edit: here are some pictures for explanation

This is the pipe layer.
[image: pipes layer]

I want to connect the startpoint (green square) with the endpoint(s) (green circle(s))
[image: connections]

This should be the outcome in the fibres layer.
[image: fibres]

Comment: Can you use [Shortest path](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#qgisshortestpathpointtopoint)?

Comment: This looks promising, i'll try that and give feedback here.

Comment: I managed to get this working. It's not an elegant solution, but it works. So thanks for the hint. I provided the sample code as answer in case someone else needs this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bera pointed out, Shortest Path is one solution, but there are some hurdles to take. The Shortest Path processing algorithm accepts only 2 points and puts the result in a layer which contains one single feature.
To get all my lines, i copied the results from each processing into a list and then created the geometry in my destination layer.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeature
from qgis import processing
pipes = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('<my_pipes>')[0]
fibres = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('<my_fibres>')[0]
startpoint = [x 
              for x in QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('<my_points>')[0].getFeatures() 
              if x['<field>'] == '<condition>'][0].geometry()
endpoint_list = [end_point 
                 for end_point in QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('<my_points>')[0].getFeatures() 
                 if end_point['<field>'] == '<condition>']
result_geometry = []
for endpoint in endpoint_list:
    endpoint_geometry = endpoint.geometry()
    params = { 'INPUT': pipes, 
                'STRATEGY': 0,
                'START_POINT': startpoint,
                'END_POINT': endpoint_geometry,
                'TOLERANCE': 0.01,
                'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
            }
    result  = processing.run("native:shortestpathpointtopoint", params)
    result_layer = result['OUTPUT']
    # gather results
    result_geometry.extend(feature.geometry() for feature in result_layer.getFeatures())
    del result_layer
# create new features in destination layer
fibres.startEditing()
for geom in result_geometry:
    new_feature = QgsFeature(fibres.fields())
    fibres.addFeature(new_feature)
    new_feature.setGeometry(geom)
    fibres.updateFeature(new_feature)
fibres.commitChanges()
```